# Trying to understand self keyword and how to use it in function chains - LUA

Tags: lua

I understand how to stack functions when creating a new table from the beginning like so :

```
Test:newNumber(5):add5():add5() --create a Number{} with Number.Num=5 then add to self.num
```

but im having trouble passing in previously existing tables as so:

```lua
function EnemyBase:isStandingOver( Object )
    local o = Object
    for k , v in pairs(Creature_Bases) do 
        if (o.x and o.y are over v.x and v.y) then 
            setmetatable( Creature_Bases[k] , self ) 
            self.__index = self
            return Creature_Bases[k]
        end
    end
end

function EnemyBase:changeSprite()
    self.Sprite = self.SpriteTest
end 

function ManageEnemies()
    for k,v in pairs(Enemies) do 
        if EnemyBase:isStandingOver( Enemies[k] ) ~= nil then 
            EnemyBase:isStandingOver( Enemies[k] ):changeSprite()
        end 
    end 
end
```

I know ill need to create a meta method table with the __index pointing to self at some point but i don't know when.

Comment: It looks like [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Could you explain what is your puprose?

Comment: Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Random comment: In order to "stack functions" like that (i.e. chain method calls), your methods have to always return `self`. I don't recommend that, because all it does is let you cram multiple statements into one, making the code harder to read. You could easily use multiple statements to do the same thing more clearly. And when a method has to return something other than `self` it can't be chained at all, unless the returned object has its own method you want to chain, which actually would make sense, because there's a new object involved which you shouldn't have to store in a variable.

Comment: I totally agree with luther. if you by chance can chain function calls feel free to do so but you shouldn't implement all your functions so you can do this. it brings too many drawbacks and does not yield any real benefit to your code

Answer (score 1):

Let's first understand what `self` is.

`function a:b() end` is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for `function a.b(self) end`

A function defined like that has a parameter `self`.

Function call `a:b()` is syntactic sugar for `a.b(a)`

A function called like that always has `a` as its first argument which inside the function ends up as parameter `self`.

So if you have defined a function like that, you have a very simple way to access table `a` through `self` from within that function without explicitly using reference `a`. This comes in handy if you want to do OOP in Lua.

Then we have to understand what the [__index metamethod](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.4) is.

> __index: The indexing access operation table[key]. This event happens when table is not a table or when key is not present in table. The
> metavalue is looked up in the metatable of table.
>
> The metavalue for this event can be either a function, a table, or any
> value with an __index metavalue. If it is a function, it is called
> with table and key as arguments, and the result of the call (adjusted
> to one value) is the result of the operation. Otherwise, the final
> result is the result of indexing this metavalue with key. This
> indexing is regular, not raw, and therefore can trigger another
> __index metavalue.

Let's use both of it in a simple constructor:

```
MyClass = {}
function MyClass:New(name)
  local instance = setmetatable({}, self)
  self.__index = self
  instance.name = name
  return instance
end

function MyClass:SayName()
  print("my name is " .. self.name)
end
```

If we now do this:

```
local myFirstInstance = MyClass:New("John")
local mySecondInstance = MyClass:New("Bob")

myFirstInstance:SayName()
mySecondInstance:SayName()
```

what's going to happen?

We know `MyClass:New()` is equivalent to `MyClass.New(MyClass)`. So in our contructor `self` refers to `MyClass`.

`local instance = setmetatable({}, self)` creates a new table and sets `self` which is `MyClass` as its metatable.

`self.__index = self` set's `MyClass` as the __index metavalue of itself.

The `name` is stored in each instance and the instance is returned.

Now if you call `myFirstInstance:SayName()`, Lua will look up `myFirstIntance["SayName"]`. It won't find anything. So it will check wether table `myFirstInstance` has a metatable and if so, if there is a __index metavalue. There is. getmetatable(myFirstInstance).__index is `MyClass` so it will now actually call `MyClass.SayName(myFirstInstance)`. So in the end, both instances will print their own name even though they do not even implement a SayName function. And `MyClass.SayName` prints both instances names without knowing even knowing the instances or even their names.

Comment: In "Function call `a:b()` is syntactic sugar for `a:b(a)`"
the latter piece of code should be `a.b(a)`. Couldn't suggest an edit because it must be at least 6 chars long